# How to change textbox focus color?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus, styles

How to change textbox focus color?

I am using different colored `TextBox`es. Example dark violet, but keyboard focus is black. This is bad combination. How I can change `TextBox` focus to gain more visual contrast?

Comment: What language / framework are you working in?

Comment: I am working C# and WPF.

Answer (score 4):

A presume you're working in WPF, so try setting the FocusVisualStyle-property.

More information about this can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If for web with javascript you can do something similar to the following

Javascript

```
function DoBlur(fld) 
{
    fld.className='normalfld';
}

function DoFocus(fld) 
{
    fld.className = 'focusfld';
}
```

Your CSS would have the following

```
.normalfld
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.focusfld
{
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

and for your text box

then your text box will have the OnFocus and OnBlur events wired up.

```
<input type="text" onblur="DoBlur(this);" onfocus="DoFocus(this);" />
```